# spring roo application in google app engine problems

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-roo

I hav been trying to develop an application using spring roo and upload in the google app engine but im coming across a lot of problems.
 Firstly,when i create the project there r no problems, i created entities and fields.. until i executed this command mvn gwt:compile gae:deploy

i get the following problems
i think its unable to download the required files from the repositories.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
F:\STS\spring-roo-1.1.1.RELEASE\bin\test1>mvn gwt:compile gae:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test1
[INFO]    task-segment: [gwt:compile, gae:deploy]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading:

Downloading: /maven.springframework.org/release/org/apache/maven/maven-pro
ject/2.0.9/maven-project-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-project:pom:2.0.9' in rep
ository sprin

Downloading: maven.springframework.org/release/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0
.9/maven-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven:pom:2.0.9' in repository
spring-maven-release (,maven.springframework.org/release)
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/apache/maven/maven/2
.0.9/maven-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven:pom:2.0.9' in repository
spring-maven-milestone (>maven.springframework.org/milestone)
Downloading: spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release)
Downloading: http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/org/apache/ma
ven/maven/2.0.9/maven-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven:pom:2.0.9' in repository
maven-gae-plugin-repo (

Downloading: maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/apache/maven/maven-s
ettings/2.0.9/maven-settings-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-settings:pom:2.0.9' in re
pository spring-maven-milestone (spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/apache/ma
ven/maven-settings/2.0.9/maven-settings-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-settings:pom:2.0.9' in re
pository spring-roo-repository (maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/org/apache/ma
ven/maven-settings/2.0.9/maven-settings-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-settings:pom:2.0.9' in re
pository maven-gae-plugin-repo (>maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repos
itory)
Downloading:

pls help,
regards,
vivek

Answer (score 0):

The pom is available there:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.9/maven-project-2.0.9.pom
 so either you don't have repo1 (or repo2) in your maven default repositories (but afaik repoX.maven.org are default repos so they should be there), either the error is somewhere else in the logs!